How do elected politicians get away with not giving straight answers?
It appears to be a de-facto norm that when an elected (or would-be elected) politician is asked a simple question, they avoid answering it directly and instead go into discourse on related (or even not) matters, and/or answer a different question.
From a point of view of a voter in a democracy, politicians are hired servants who are to report to their bosses — the people. When a report constantly does not give straight answers, they are usually fired and replaced with someone more dependable.
How come that not giving straight answers has become a norm for politicians in democracies? How do such politicians politically survive? Why does the public put up with them? Why is it apparently not beneficial for a politician (in terms of winning support of the people) to strive to give direct answers? (I mean, if it was beneficial, most politicians probably would, wouldn't they?).

Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/35456/why-do-politicians-refuse-to-answer-hypothetical-questions

Didn't your own exposition clearly Answer the Question as written, describing exactly how politicians do that?
Were you really interested in why the opposition, the media or the electorate let the politicians get away with what you described?

@RobbieGoodwin I can't see any "expositions" in my question describing how politicians get away. I only expose their modus operandi of avoiding answering questions directly (in the first paragraph), not of getting away with it.

I don't understand what you're hoping to get round, or why.
I thought 'How politicians get away… with (stuff)' was the point of your Question.
I thought your own exposition clearly Answered the Question as written, describing exactly how politicians do that. Did it not? Is 'exposition' unclear?
Anyway, where did you get the idea that 'When a report constantly does not give straight answers, they are usually fired and replaced with someone more dependable…'?
If 'a report' worked in English still, how many instances could you cite of anyone being being fired or replaced for that?

Was the original question 'How do elected politicians get away with not giving straight answers…' or did I miss something?

If 'exposition' doesn't work for you, can you say why not, please?

Sorry, and how could  claiming they 'only expose their modus operandi of avoiding answering directly…' not automatically Answer your own Question?
Don't most people here agree?
To turn that right around, does anyone here not agree?

This is part of [at least of the Western] culture. Communication schools teach it. Because it works in general, no matter if you're selling shoes or your political programme.
Countries which formally penalize politicians for telling lies are few. Those which formally penalize them for avoiding a question, none, AFAIK. The difference also exists in Western law, where you're allowed not to answer questions, in many settings.
I would not  (a priori) conclude though that if politician A does it 90% of the time and politician B does it 10% of the time, both have equal chances of being elected, ceteris paribus.

Although this is mostly reinforcing the Q, it was easy to find a study (albeit quite limited in scope, in terms of sampling) concluding that "making political points was by far the most frequent form non-reply used by politicians, following by attacking the question."
Alas, finding studies of whether doing this [more] often has some electoral impact are hard[er] to find. But at least in laboratory experiments, accusations of evasiveness do seem to have an effect. The more interesting point (there) perhaps is that in the absence of such explicit accusations of evasiveness, few subjects seemed to care/detect the condition themselves.
An extreme example from another paper:

even
in the extreme case of a politician answering a question about the War on Terror
with a response about universal health care, one fourth of study participants still
did not realize that the topic of the response differed from the question topic
(Rogers & Norton, 2011).

The latter paper even opens with this 'received wisdom' quote...

Don’t answer the question you were asked. Answer the question you
wish you were asked.
-- Robert McNamara, describing the lessons he learned during his time
as Secretary of Defense during the Vietnam War (Morris, Williams, &
Ahlberg, 2004)

(The quote is slightly modified from the original. But the latter article even notes that "that rule has taken on a life of its own in the modern business world".)
Relatedly, politicians do accuse each other of evasiveness, to a signficant degree, according to one empirical study, at least in the US context.
And one might also add that even when they [kinda] answer a question, ambiguity appears to work in the politician's favor.
At least some academics have also highlighted the "other side of the coin", namely that politicians are more often asked a biased/loaded or at least 'conflictual' questions (that highlight inconsistencies in statements etc.) by professional interviewers than by the general public.
Another point raised in that paper (albeit not with much empirical data) is that pleading ignorance seems to work less well than thought-terminating clichés like pleading modernization. (Of course, the two are not entirely interchangeable strategies in all contexts.) But, at least [some] political communication theorists think the later variety of answers are a preferable form of equivocation.
Another perhaps interesting point in the US context, although I'm unsure of its significance in a grander scheme, is that direct refusals to answer were more often found in press conferences (with one politician) while topical shifts were more prevalent in debates with multiple politician participants. Perhaps because [many] more people watch the latter kinds of debates, it's considered a less risky strategy to topic-shift than to evade/refuse-to-answer in a more direct manner.

But why is it a cultural thing? Culture isn't simply happening onto us. It must have an origin and also maybe some kind of reason behind. One alternative could be "I don't want to answer that question, please ask another one." That would waste less time for everyone.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution: I'm not going to discuss cultural [co-]evolution in this answer, because that tends to become quite speculative, and it's generally outside the scope of this site. Maybe ask on Psychology SE that Q.

Okay, but simply to back up the statement, the answer could maybe dive a bit more into how we know that it's a cultural thing.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution About "I dont want to answer ...", maybe we should also look at what consists of an 'culturally acceptable' answer in other contexts. For example doctors in my experience rarely say: "Honestly, I don't know", instead they answer a different question, talk in generalities, or just make something up that sounds plausible.

@Ivana Only tangential here, but once I had a doctor who told me he doesn't know what I have and asked me to wait a bit while he goggles it and reads up on it. My respect of him grew instead of shrinking.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution The issue with comparing a doctor to politics, is that in the case of a diagnosis, there is usually one correct answer. There are consequences for incorrect or non-answers when it comes to medicine. In politics, many questions don't have a correct answer, and usually all answers have consequences. Many seemingly innocent questions do carry consequences, as answers have to be careful not to counter anything previously said or done, and try to avoid making predictions or promises that the politician can then be quoted on. Non-answers avoid the consequences.

Countries which formally penalize politicians for telling lies are few => that's cool, do you think you could an example in your answer?

@JonathanReez: https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/41857/18373

@DavidS "Non-answers avoid the consequences." Personally maybe, but I feel it's also kind of a fallacy. It mostly avoids discussion, but doesn't necessarily avoids decisions, which will be made anyway and also cannot protect from any real world consequences. I mean like for example: not talking about global warming is not a guaranteed way to avoid it (it's only a failsafe way to avoid doing anything about it). Voters could then simply say: "he/she didn't gave answers on that one, probably isn't interested in the subject and/or has no expertise in it and probably wouldn't do anything about it".

We are dependent on the interviewers to ask good questions and to not accept vague or simply non sequitur.  You can find plenty of outrage about politicians not answering the questions they were asked or the questions being pathetic but the people who don't like that don't have a lot of ability to change things.
Partially this happens because the politicians go to venues where the interviewers are their supporters.  This results in them being asked "questions" like, "Lots of people think you are great and thank god for your presidency.  What would you like to say to those people?" and also in the politician being allowed to just state their talking points regardless of the question asked, while the interviewer just nods along.
The second factor is the interviewers' concerns about retaliation.  If they are perceived as being too mean or unfair then they, and their organisation, may not be given the chance again.  Reputable journalists have found themselves passed over for questions at White House briefings while distinctly substandard news organisations that do lob softballs are called on frequently.
There's a well known, in Ireland at least, case from 20 years ago where a reporter from Ireland's national news network, RTE, interviewed George Bush.  After this interview the subsequent ones that were to take place were cancelled and the Irish embassy was sent a letter of complaint.
I found a contemporaneous article about it, and the actual video from CSPAN so you can judge for yourself what happened.
Personally I think the complaint that the interviewer "didn't let him answer the question" is actually that she didn't let him avoid the question by talking about something else.
Now, I can assure you that RTE largely didn't care that they would likely never be allowed to interview George Bush again.  If they were CNN or the New York Times they might be a lot more concerned.
So, to sum up.  Two reasons:

The interviewer and audience don't care.
The interviewer feels constrained in how far they can go out of fear of retaliation, and the audience has no ability to affect that.


Isn't the question then why the audience doesn't care? It seems not to but why doesn't it?

+1; BTW, Japan and South Korea used to be more famous for this kind of retaliation, i.e. leaving out unfavorable press from any 'scoops' of government decisions etc., in order to reduce their audience.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution The two reasons I gave at the end represent different people.  The people that don't care whether the politician answers the question are the ones that support that politician.  They think they already know everything they need to know and are not interested in hearing anything that might change their mind.  The other type of person might get frustrated that the politicians are allowed lie and/or not answer but they don't have any real ability to change things.  They can't force the interviewers to change and there are no alternatives (any that pop up will disappear)

I think this does actually point to the culprit- interviewers letting them get away with it. The BBC I've noticed is much better about insisting on proper answers and picking at weak ones than US-based interviewers. Its really amusing listening to many American right-wing surrogates getting interviewed by the BBC, because many times they've never developed a sensible media answer for their more controversial positions rather other than the simple deflection, since that always worked for them before. Those folks are at a complete loss for what to say when actually pressed.

Just for entertainment, perhaps of a bitter sweet nature, here's a clip of Jeremy Paxman in a BBC interview asking the same question 12 times in a row as the politician repeatedly answers a different question.  (Note this is from 25 years ago, the BBC doesn't do this sort of thing any more)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IqU77I40mS0&t=8s

@EricNolan Part of the reason they don't do this, is because it turns out that the audience doesn't like it. BBC Radio 4's Today program is/used to be famous for this style of interviewing. This has lead to a large backlash against the program with people saying they don't listern because they find it too combative, and in the end they don't learn anything from the interview.

The repeating of the question starts at 4:10 in the video linked by Eric Nolan.

An interview or debate is not witness testimony in court or a deposition, where a responsive answer is legally required.
When voters are considering someone for an elected public office, particularly when someone is running for President, they are looking for someone who comes across as a "boss" and not someone who comes across as a "servant", contrary to the question's assumption. Candidates "who are perceived as strong and inspiring leaders are much more likely to be preferred by the voters."
Refusing to be bound by what an interviewer or debate moderator, who will have lower status than the candidate if the candidate is elected, is a rhetorical tool that allows the candidate to assert authority and come across like a "boss", rather than as a meek follower or servant who simply does what they are told by a person who will ultimately have lower status than them. It is about showing that the candidate is capable of maintaining control of important social interactions.
This rhetorical technique is a close cousin of the rhetorical trick of reframing a question.
The likely voter is projecting the way that the candidate interacts with the person asking the question onto the way the candidate would be expected to act in a negotiation with a foreign head of state or other VIP on their behalf.
Because voters are ultimately at least as interested in the ultimate question of how effective the candidate will be as a boss when elected as they are about the answer to the question asked, this rhetorical tactic doesn't leave a negative impression with most likely voters watching the interview or debate.
In the same way, all sorts of people in all sorts of settings have a cognitive bias towards people who sound confident and like they know what they are doing, even if someone who is actually more knowledgable also provides a more qualified answer.
Both unapologetically providing a non-responsive answer that advances the candidate's agenda, and sounding confident (even when they actually aren't), are dominance signals to which other people naturally respond positively when choosing a leader.

So the exercise was to please show us how to not answer these questions. I wonder how they would responded then if they would have been asked questions that they like to answer.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution A good speaker has a toolbox of rhetorical tools, and mixes them up. If you get a softball question, you provide your quotable polished short quip or monolog (and point to it if accused of being generally non-responsive and defiant). If you get a question that detracts from the narrative you want to tell, then you use the question to segue yourself into that narrative rather than answering the question that was being asked. If the interviewer or moderate tries too hard to pin you down, they come across badly to the audience.

One might expect reframing indeed to be viewed positively in some contexts, and by some voters, but negatively in/by others. Alas, I didn't have much luck finding any empirical studies that try to delineate such parameters, although in a pretty polarized context like the US, one may guess what some such factors may be, to some extent.

"...you use the question to segue yourself into that narrative rather than answering the question that was being asked...." So as a politician you basically give the same speech over and over and over again. Don't people become bored with it?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution It is boring for the politician, but the audience is usually different for each event. Also, when a candidate answers a question, the candidate doesn't give their entire repertoire of speeches at once in response to that question. In response to a question about gun control, the candidate might respond with an answer about criminal punishments for violent gang members instead. In response to a question about health insurance, the candidate might respond with an answer about grocery store monopolies driving up prices and affecting health, etc.

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever The problem with scientifically studying the issue is even worse than that. As another answer notes, there are a handful of studies on the issue. But, even in the rare cases where studies are done, investigator bias in devising the study and interpreting it is a huge problem. Doing a "clean" and neutral experiment type study is extremely difficult. Focus groups and in-depth analysis of particular cases is more fruitful.


How come that not giving straight answers has become a norm for politicians in democracies?

As suggested by the already accepted answer, this is cultural. I want to expand on that a bit. Business executives and other public speakers do this sort of thing just as much, so it's entirely normalized. Even if you invite a speaker to a middle or high school and a bright student comes up with an insightful, pointed question, that student will almost certainly walk away with a non-answer that is at most vaguely on the theme of what was asked. So people grow up learning to accept that. (It might even be taken as a sign of neurodivergence when people appear not to accept it.)
Aside from that, it's worth looking in to how debate clubs and competitions work in the US. There are a lot of really heinous (IMHO), sophistic rhetorical strategies (in particular "spreading") that are largely about gaming the scoring rules of the debate and not about actually being convincing. Intellectual honesty is really not at a premium.

How do such politicians politically survive?

They're all this way, so the question is moot.

Why does the public put up with them?

Because they don't have an option.

Why is it apparently not beneficial for a politician (in terms of winning support of the people) to strive to give direct answers?

A lot of questions asked at debates are "traps" or otherwise biased - an attempt by the moderator to get across a critique of one candidate or the other. And even when that isn't the case, each candidate's base might easily see things that way. Answering a question directly entails accepting its framing.

(I mean, if it was beneficial, most politicians probably would, wouldn't they?).

I know this must sound absurd at first, but it really does seem possible that they simply haven't tried. That would be because there aren't qualified politicians out there who want the job and are capable of thinking on their feet and answering a question honestly while also dodging traps and making themselves look good.
It's a lot harder than it sounds. Candidates in Presidential debates, in particular, seem to be clearly relying on canned lines and slogans that their staff have carefully selected for rhetorical effect - and therefore they will rhetorically move heaven and earth to insert those lines and slogans. It's simply not feasible for them to come up with such quips extemporaneously while staying on topic. There is a lot of evidence that election results are largely driven by charisma; in the minds of average voters, that charisma likely correlates more with slick rhetoric than with actually knowing one's platform well enough to answer arbitrary questions off the cuff.

The part in the middle sounds a bit like catch 22. Voters don't have a choice because all politicians are alike. All politicians are alike, probably because voters fall for it more than for honesty. Impossible to break through at least in the short term. But at least on this platform, we manage to more or less answer questions fairly straightforward. Probably not unbiased but at least there is not much incentive to answer something else instead... most of the time.

"But at least on this platform, we manage to more or less answer questions fairly straightforward." - well, yes; this platform is about answering questions, and is not about self-promotion.

"not about self-promotion". More true on P.SE than on some of the engineering stacks actually. Some people post there mostly to boost their consultancy business/exposure. However, they can't just get away with advertisements.

People elect them again, that's how.
A good politician knows what subjects matter to their voter. When voters care about something, politicians in touch with the voters know that they have to state their opinion and position on it in a manner that doesn't upset the voter against them. In a multi-cultural society, with diverse opinions, and even diverse levels of education and class, politicians need to be even more careful with what they talk about because the potential to upset a certain segment of voters is higher. Thus, they also develop different ways to communicate with different voter groups more candidly and openly than through the mass media, to gain a voters' trust.
Remember, that we aren't talking about a discourse between individuals but a "one to many" and "many to many" level of communication where mob psychology becomes applicable.

So they basically just talk something to make the time of the interview go by?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution No. How they communicate depends on the audience. For e.g. a smart presidential candidate in the US, who maybe pro-choice, will avoid talking about abortion with a pro-life audience so as to not earn those voters' ire (who may otherwise still vote for the candidate).

Well they're both pro-choice...

Tout à point, sfxedit

@TheChaz2.0 "Well they're both pro-choice..." But maybe (very likely even) not equally pro-choice. If only there was someone asking them about the details (federal level or states, how many weeks, medical counsel other indications, why they appointed judges who were against this, their relation to their party in this regard,...) and they would answer these questions. If only that would have happened, voters could make themselves a much more clear picture what their real stance is towards abortion. Wouldn't this be helpful information. At least as a voter I would like that.

@TheChaz2.0 You don't judge politicians by what they say, but by what they do. Saying they are both "pro-choice" isn't correct because there's also the possibility that a candidate may actually not care about it one way or the other - in other words, they may not have a strong opinion about that political topic, the way their target voters do. (To me, it seems like neither Biden not Trump actually care about the topic personally. And so they are happy to let the courts or the legislature decide on it, and then point a finger at them to claim credit or blame them and earn some political points)

Political success in the US has always been reliant (to some extent) on the projection of strength, and this is only magnified by modern social media and the 24 hour news cycle. Candidates must (first and foremost) appear to be strong, decisive, tenacious, and in control, and a slip on any of those qualities is a death knell for a campaign. This is part of the psychology of US politics: campaigns try to expose or create some fear or vulnerability in (some segment of) the public, so that the candidate can step up and become the pillar of strength against that fear or vulnerability. People are urged to choose between competing fears, setting aside nuanced issues of fact and policy to choose the person they feel is strongest against some oncoming threat.
Giving a 'straight' or 'real' answer in the US poses risks:

It exposes the nuances, subtleties, and interpretive difficulties of real-world situations, which can make a candidate look weak or indecisive.
It creates a 'hard' positions that opponents can use for attacks and disputations.
It opens the door for endless inquiry into whether a candidate practices what s'he preaches.

In other words, 'straight' or 'real' answers become broad avenues to attack a candidate's character, giving opponents an opportunity to cast the candidate as weak, indecisive, malleable, or pandering. These all reduce a candidate's ability to project strength. It's much better (in terms of political pragmatics) to derail a question onto a topic the candidate can speak strongly and confidently on, not to let a question derail the candidate into murky, indeterminate waters. Much of the game of US politics is to make an opponent look weak, irresolute, frantic, or hapless; an opponent successfully cast in that light will never win an election.
Until this (admittedly crappy) form of emotive politics disappears, it is on us to look past the rhetoric and decide who is most competent to hold a given position. Competent candidates will play the game, but will reveal their competence in their heart and their consistency; incompetent actors will expose themselves through their strict adherence to the game

But do voters on average rather like this superficial projection of strength over discussion of detailed political stances or do voters actually on average not appreciate it but politicians practice it anyway, because they can get away with it? I mean, some if not many voters aren't very interested in politics. They may simply not care much about the actual content.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution: Uhm… We're not entirely in the realm of the human forebrain here. A lot of political posturing is an extension of pre-linguistic pack behavior. Social animals (doge, chimps, bovines, etc) don't necessarily 'like' or 'dislike' dominance/submission attitudes; they perform them reactively. Humans add a cognitive/intellectual layer to this, but the gut-level reaction to the projection of strength is something like a sense of release or relief. People instinctively align to it, because it implies order and direction for the pack.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution: This isn't bad in and of itself, but the problem is that (for political leaders) emotional reactions are a more reliable avenue to success than clear policy positions. And in the worst-case (nationalisms) the entire goal of the movement is to disrupt the sense of order and direction in society and project extreme (even rabid) strength to try and drive the populace away from cognitive thought into a pure pack dominance/submission mindset. That is unfortunately effective, at least int the (comparative) short-term.

So, it's because of our animalistic instincts, way of "group thinking"?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution: Well, calling it 'instinct' might be a bit oversimplified. Attitudes are learned pre-verbal behaviors. It's like the way you can drive a car without consciously thinking about moving your hands and feet; you habituate the actions. We learn a lot of our social attitudes through interactions with parents and childhood peers, and deference to strength is one of the earliest and strongest attitudes we develop. As adults we overcome that to a degree, but the roots of it are always there. It's like a default mode we return to in moments of insecurity.

So Donald Trump and Kamala Harris could also just fight it out in the literal sense. I guess in this way Donald Trump's age compared to Kamala Harris's is probably playing against him.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution: We shouldn't underestimate the subtlety of this. Projection of strength mens the projection of intellectual, emotional, and even moral strength, not just physical strength. An unwarranted physical attack would likely be perceived as a moral or emotional weakness. Trump's age doesn't work against him half as much as his immaturity does; the fact that Harris repeatedly needled him into loosing his cool established her as thoroughly dominant.

And not just there. Although you can see why some Americans admire other countries systems... in some regards.

Your question reminds me of myself at around 30 years old asking myself why lawyers in the city were reluctant to take a cut-and-dried-winnable case for me against a major local employer.
The penny dropped in my jukebox soon enough. Lawyers - like many other people - were in business and were not providing a social service for the greater glory of God. They wouldn't challenge a major local employer on behalf of a cash-strapped individual because they coveted the idea of getting legal work from them and other similar businesses. And business related legal work was emotionally easier and far better paid than a hard-fought litigation on behalf of a single individual.
Pols are "in business" in another sense. Their very survival as practioners depends on their ongoing electability. Electability gives them a degree of power both locally and within parliament. It demands respect from friend and foe alike. And if cultivated carefully it can lead to them becoming a "serious political player" in their region - something that can lead to high office or influence with those they support in attaining it.
Electability is usually - though not always - jeopardized by giving straight answers to frank questions. Hence the many "helicopter trips" around the subject of the question they want to avoid answering directly, hence the "quantum conversations" with themselves that bring in as many peripheral or analagous situations as they can think of.
All pols do it and they can easily justify doing it by saying that the tabloid press will twist anything they say into something more controversial - which is true, especially in the silly season and the fall months after political scribes return from mental holiday with a zeal to provide for the public's right to know.

Sometimes you don't know the 'right' answer
As this question is phrased, I think you're seeking an answer based on national or state level politics, but I want to give an alternate point of view from the local level. I've run for the local school board on two separate occasions (never won). For various reasons, the local political scene in our area is very contentious on a litany of different issues.
In the first race I ran, I was on my own, and nobody was telling me what to do. For the purposes of that race, I responded to written questions I was sent by a local reporter. The questions focused on several issues and some I needed to look up in order to provide a cogent response to, so that's what I did. For example, one focused on a sexual health directive issued by the governor that was frankly a huge pain in the neck to actually find the language of (there were plenty of complaints about it online suggesting that the governor was condoning some pretty gross things happening to kids, but the actual text just suggested that at the 2nd grade level is when some classes under the 'sex ed' category begins and those recommended lesson plans just focused on helping kids understand who they could talk to about things that made them uncomfortable). A second focused on rights for trans kids, which really just needed a thoughtful approach. Thankfully, I wasn't asked those questions in-person, because if I were, I'd just have to spin to something else because it would've been risky to answer when I don't know enough about the material.
Notably, in the first race, I was asked to an interview by my opposition's supporters, but they ended up declining when I requested they provide a written list of the subjects they wanted to talk about. Frankly, I found it disingenuous that they wanted me to give them my time and open myself up to potential harassment without allowing me to properly prepare.
Sometimes you have to think about more than just you
For the second race I ran, I was joined by two other folks, we formed a block together, and a local political group we were part of helped us with funding. As part of that race, we were pretty much told that we couldn't answer questions that the three of us hadn't already discussed together because it was important for us to be united in our views. Not adhering to this rule creates a problem down the line where the folks working to get funding for us want to know that they're not wasting the effort because we can't present a united front.
This ultimately led to us not answering anything, which I genuinely found annoying, but the fact of the matter is that we were all working adults and finding times that worked for all three of us to sit down and identify major issues we wanted to ensure we had consensus on wasn't really viable (never mind that we were regularly walking all over town delivering flyers). Bear in mind, this is local politics so we come armed with what we think is important as individuals, we don't have consultants giving us polls telling us the the litany of issues that other people are worrying about.
Additionally, as part of that second race, I was asked questions by our opposition's supporters whose only purpose was to try and create ammunition to be used against me. As I stated before, the second race a local political group helped us with funding, the opposition wanted me to answer a bunch of 'gotcha' questions on that matter. I would like to simply say, "I don't know the answer because I want to run for school board because I care about that and I don't care about obscure election finance rules." But that would've opened me up to some bad out-of-context quotes, so in such situations, "no comment," is the best possible answer.
Written Q&As are probably better, but that probably only works with neutral questions
To summarize, I think you might get a lot more straight answers from politicians if the questions came in a written format and allowed for a written response. This approach allows the respondent to properly think and research the question before responding, but additionally, if there is some kind of cagey wording of the question they can reframe it a bit in their response.
For example, maybe my written response to the 'gotcha' question above becomes, "We're choosing to work with a team of folks who are knowledgeable about things like election finance law and , so that we can focus our efforts on the priorities of the school board."
Ironically, I still didn't answer the question, however, it wasn't really a good question to begin with. However, I think it's a better answer than choosing to attack the question.

In case anyone's curious, while I lost, both my running mates won. 2 out of 3 ain't bad in politics.

I think the question needs a more objective consideration.

@Trunk I think you're right, but I think having the POV of someone who's run for office can be helpful since it hadn't yet been posted. After the Trump administration, I was inspired to try something and that was what I did. And it was a good thing (even if I didn't win), as I gained a lot of useful perspective of the kinds of things elected and prospective officials go through. So I felt it helpful to share it per the Back It Up criteria described in the Good Subjective, Bad Subjective

I'm not sure there is one answer to that question as that can be a combination of various factors which can be differently important for different people and situations.
Which coincidentally is a non-answer of mine. The problem is a good universal answer to a question is pretty hard, if possible at all, as a question depends not just on it's content, but also it's context.
So for example if you're asked an exam question or prompted something in a quiz, then the answer is expected to be a single word or catch phrase that you should produce almost without thinking as both the person asking the question as well as you the person responding are supposed to know the answer and to know THE SAME ANSWER as there is basically only 1 correct one.
So idk:

What is "force"?

Well in a physics exam it's mass times acceleration.
While in a discussion between professionals or people not accustomed to any if these terms you might rather describe it as some attractive or repulsive interaction between physical objects. Maybe you would give examples, to try to make it more vivid and descriptive. Maybe you'd need to explain other terms as well before you could get to really give an understanding of what force is.
So already you went from a short concise answer to something much lenghtier and fuzzy and the more difficult the topic and the less you understand it yourself the harder it gets to describe the whole thing concise instead of just reiterating what you see (which is lengthy and incoherent depending on how much coherence you already figured out).
Also "force" might not even be about physics but could be about the Star Wars movies or political actions, power, creativeness, violence, energy and various other synonyms that could be related or could lead into entirely different scenarios.
So if you're promptet with a "simple question" and insufficient knowledge of context, that very much invites to writing long meandering answers because you want to cover as much ground as possible to potentially cover the answer that the other person might have expect (and if only by accident).
So even with best intentions (and that is not a given), there can be a tendency for that. Another problem is that the setup of a debate further increases the problem of a missing context.
Like if you have a specific problem and ask a specific politician about it, you can ask follow up questions, remind them to stay on topic, can provide examples of your own and help them (in your own interest) to get the context that you're looking for and produce a content that is relevant to that.
The problem is that most discussions with politiicans are rather 1-to-many-relations. So even if people can agree on the same question, they nonetheless might have asked it for very different reasons and contexts and expect very different answers, so there's a good chance if you answer it to the satisfaction of one context, that you will disappoint a majority of other people asking the question. And the moderator can only do so much to mitigate that as they can only give their own context which itself would suffer from the same problem of not being necessarily representative.
So there's already an incentive to give long catchall answers instead of concise ones.
Or you'd have the reverse problem, that if the candidate would give concise answers they might be differently interpretable so that in the end you still don't know what they stand for and it's more about sentiment than content. Not to mention that the more topics you want to cover and the least amount of time, the more rushed and misleading this is going to get.
And if you add an angle of pressure, of being examined and being agressive investigated, you even more so encourage talk that is not "legally binding". Especially in the current meme-culture where every microexpression of yours could be taken out of context and being looped into it's own existence. So if you give an answer to a very narrow and specific question that could be taken out of context as a general political statement of "We should do X" or stuff like that. So one might be further incentivized to make concrete statements and proposals where it matters and to avoid making statements that can be constructed like that in "casual" conversation (outside of the institutions).
With all that being said you also don't just want to avoid looking incompetent and giving answers that are hard to factually attack, but you also want to insert your politics make proposals, get people to recognize the problems that you plan to tackle and so much more. So you kinda have to squeeze those in as well as otherwise your platform is being used by others, be it media ("Look we got access to the time of important people") or your opponent who might try to shift the conversation to their topics.
Also in addition to all of that you might want to develop a USP (unique selling point), so something that makes YOU the right candidate rather than anybody else with the same platform.
Now to be fair that is already kinda iffy for a democracy as that should NOT be about cults of personality and superficialities but about substance, but unfortunately the rediscovered concept of democracy is often pretty novel and quite some are apparently still stuck in a mindset of following leaders and electing bosses rather than seeing democracy as exercising one's own powers and granting someone a mandate to fulfill this job on a day to day basis, while staying accountable to the people for whom they speak.
So as we've gone over the less insiduous parts of why that could be the case. One might also mention things like "Herrschaftssprache" roughly "language of power". That is the sort of language that make the people addressed with it feel small, insignificant and give them the impression that the topics are over their head and that they should be fine with someone else taking that burden for them.
So if you speak in clear easy to understand language and explain your reasoning, ideas, aspirations, hopes and fears and whatnot, than people might actually understand them and get involved. Might criticize or try to amend them or might themselves try to get into politics in the sense of "if they can do that, I could do that same shit but better, easily".
Which can be good for democracy as people might get a more realistic insight into how things actually work, where the pitfalls are, what needs to be considered and what the pressing problems are, why decisions are made the way they are and so on.
But which also might create problems for politicians because their job is in danger, but also because a short and concise language might also be deceiving. Like if you explain it to a 5 year old, you do so in an attempt to lay a foundation and nurture their interest, but you don't expect the 5 year old to directly apply it or at least not beyond the scale of a controlled environment. So it could also mean that people fall for some Dunning-Kruger-effect where the point that they understand something makes them believe that they understood everything and that you "just need to do X" and everything is fine, ignoring that these actually might be more complex issues where you don't know the answer but where various approaches have benefits and downsides that people are already discussing and where the one fit-all-solution might not be as near as you think it is.
So you have to walk the fine line of not making it look more simple than it is and to not make it look more complex than it is either. Trying to push your agenda while not deceiving people about the other options or pitfalls of that.
So all in all there are a number of reasons for why that is somewhat inevitable, sometimes even legitimated and warranted, but sure on the other hand you also have people who viciously exploit that to "play the game" and perform the actions that are to some extend expected but with the completely opposite goal of remaining unaccountable and nebulous or to convey an impression of character rather than say anything substantative and so on.
Yet to distinguish the two might not be done with a neat simple catch all solution either, so it's probably not easy to avoid that altogether especially in a field like politics where "the correct answer" is less of a thing you memorize and more of a nudging of preferences on the question of "what should we do next".
So if you want to press them on an issue you'd rather make it one person asking their particular questions and really getting to the point of them, but that would be a very different setup of conversations and it would be hard to scale if 1 politician should answer to millions of people in 1:1 interviews.

To some extent, it is the case that if a voter refused to vote for any candidate who wasn't always giving straight answers, they would no longer be able to vote for any candidate at all. All the other politicians do it too, so this can't possibly be a criterion that actually causes voters not to vote for one in particular.
Politics involves lots of negotiation and compromise. If a politician says "I will under no/all circumstances vote for/implement this-or-that policy when I am in office", it might later happen that they break that promise because that is the result of a negotiation (with a coalition partner, between branches of government, with a foreign government, …); in that case it would have certainly been more honest if they had not given such a "straight answer".
The current Federal President of Austria, Alexander Van der Bellen, published a book shortly before being elected into that office, in which he tells us the following: Once after becoming the leader of his party, he was going to be interviewed on live television. He had been told four central messages that he had to somehow tell viewers during that interview. After the interview, his media coach asked him: "Why did you not answer the question?" He answered: "What, did I not do that?" They watched the interview again and he had to agree that he hadn't answered the question, but instead simply noticed "now it is my turn" and concentrated on getting those four messages to viewers. He explains he had to unlearn that behavior.
(If you want to read it yourself, this is from page 79 of the 1st edition of Die Kunst der Freiheit by Alexander Van der Bellen, ISBN 978-3-85033-922-3.)
The same politician, in his last speech before the National Council (starting at 3:30, official transcript), explained that when he was a new politician, he wasn't prepared that he had to have an opinion on everything immediately. (He actually continues to tell the story from the previous paragraph starting at 4:20.)


I don't have to outrun the bear, I only have to outrun you.

Most elections are not about an individual qualifying, but about a group competing. While naively both select "the best", the respective constraints mean the results vary in practice.
There are a few features of elections that allow or even encourage the winners to have vague positions:

Someone will win: It is practically guaranteed that someone gets elected.  Not electing anyone usually would require almost all voters to agree to withhold their vote, which is an unstable situation as anyone still voting gets much more impact.
Most people are not experts in most things: Every election at large enough scope covers way more topics than any individual voter can understand. For every individual topic, the majority of voters will have little competence even if anyone is an expert in some topics.
The number of possible positions is huge: Simple combinatorics mean that positions grow quickly with the number of open questions.1 The number of positions will certainly be higher than the number of candidates and seats.

So what do these points actually mean for elections?

Most voters have no optimal candidate: It’s practically guaranteed that every candidate is just a compromise for most voters. This means it doesn’t matter if candidates do everything right, because that isn’t expected to begin with.
Candidates don’t reach voters with expert positions: Being above average competence in any topic has very low payoff since only very few voters can tell the difference or appreciate the details.2 A vague position is at least as effective and needs much less investment, allowing to reach many more people overall.
Candidates compete against each other, not an ideal: There are no extra points or even requirements for not being vague. It is sufficient for vagueness to be effective in order to not disqualify anyone.

So all in all, being vague is a winning strategy with lots of upside and no disqualifying downsides. Democracy is simply not like hiring, nor like reviewing reports of an employee. The scale of voters, positions and candidates makes for an entirely different selection dynamic.

1 Even with just ten yes/no topics there are 1024 possible positions. Add just one more topic and now there are 2048 positions.
2What people can tell is if someone thinks they are an expert. This is a good way to not be liked by many people.


How do elected politicians get away with not giving straight answers?

A hostile or inexperienced interviewer may ask a bad or leading question. In those cases, directly answering the question means the answer isn't very good. In those cases, you need to find a way to answer the question in a better way, and it's not always by giving a straight/direct answer.
Reason 1:
Politicians "get away" with it because the voters often don't want a straight answer, they want to hear more than a 1 or 2 word answer. If an interviewer asks a yes/no question, a politician is still expected to have more than a yes/no answer. This may sound like it's not a straight answer, since a straight answer is yes/no, but it's a lot more interesting to listen to.
Generally, a good answer is considered one that involves an interesting story. There's usually background information as to why a candidate or politician has made a decision and it's important to include that in the answer.
Example:
Q: "Are you for or against gun control?"
Bad Answer: "I'm for it."
Better Answer: "With as many school aged children that are getting killed in schools, and even their houses, when kids find or are given loaded guns, I'm for more gun control in order to save these young lives. I want to make sure that people who threaten violence are quickly and safely prevented from doing so. I'm for universal background checks. I don't want to ban all guns, just the ones that have repeatedly shown just how deadly they are in mass shootings."
The first answer is bad because it's simply not interesting. The second answer tries to bring the listener into the discussion with a story they can relate to.
Reason 2:
It's harder for the opposition to twist what's said into a soundbite that says something completely different than what was actually said. It's part of why politicians typically don't give yes/no answers.
The reason why the first answer in my example above is bad is because the opposition can twist it to mean nearly anything from a loosely regulated "red flag" laws to even a complete ban on all guns. Or the opposition may say that the gun laws they've supported in the past lack the ability to enforce them.
The second answer is better in that it gives solid reasoning for their decision and gives an outline for what their decision actually is. It also gives them a foundation to stand on when the opposition starts making accusations.
Reason 3:
There's often a lot of context that goes into the answer of a "simple" question. An interviewer may ask a yes/no question that's completely off-topic and lacking context, so a smart politician will add the context.
For example, an interview could ask an extremely loaded question like "Have you stopped beating your wife?" If a politician didn't give the context that they never beat their wife, then their answer would have to be "no", since they never started, but that sounds bad, so they may try to say "yes", and then they are accused of beating their wife, or accused of lying if they prove they never started beating their wife.
That example is extremely obviously a loaded question, but others are more subtle.
Potential questions that are loaded and aren't looking for a simple yes/no answer could be:

"Joe, when's your next nap scheduled?"
"Kamala, when did you decide to be black?"
"Donald, when are you planning your next bankruptcy?"
"JD, when are you planning another fake bear attack?"

For most people, questions like that should be ignored, but a politician will likely get shredded by their opposition for not answering even these rude and completely indefensible questions. The typical idea is "they can't answer a simple question", even though it's most definitely not a simple question.
In my earlier example about gun control, that's also a loaded question (at least in the USA) because it's an extremely hot topic and people tend to be extremely divided on the issue. For instance, the majority of Americans do want better gun control laws, but even they differ on what those look like. And there is a very loud minority segment of Americans that believe the Second Amendment strictly prohibits any kind of regulations on firearms.
Postscript:
I numbered my reasons, but they aren't in any particular order, nor am I trying to give an exhaustive list of reasons for politicians not giving a straight answer. There are plenty of good and valid reasons in the other answers. I'm simply adding these reasons to the mix.
Yes, some of my examples aren't kind. They aren't meant to be, as they are meant to be examples of why a politician or candidate may not want to give a straight answer to those questions. If those kinds of hostile questions were never asked and the opposition always played pair/straight with the answers, politicians would likely be able to give more straight answers.

The answer lies in the tag used:  debate.
Who should "hold the politician accountable?"
Per ohwilleke's answer, a debate is not a court of law, but I will approach things from a slightly different angle than them.
Yesterday, after the high profile debate that probably motivated this question, I went to look at one of "the other side's" media outlets.
Of course, the commentators there viewed things differently than I did.
They complained that their candidate had been treated more harshly with regards to fact-checking.  Never mind that one of the probable causes for their annoyance seems to be trending as a post-debate meme ;-)
They still have a point:  one candidate got called out more than the other.
This is a slippery slope.  If an on-the-spot factcheck is controversial, on a statement that a candidate has clearly made, this applies doubly to this question's really fuzzy notion of "evasion".

This isn't to say that candidates should be allowed to straight out lie during debates.  It is to say that fact-checking - a considerably clearer task - is already contentious and pushing hard for clarity involves a lot more judgment calls on who is shirking on the answering.


I am asking about not giving straight answers
*

Moderators in a debate should NOT be in the business of calling out evasion by either candidate.  That way lies the moderators having to judge who is being less forthcoming vs more forthcoming and them taking sides.
In a court of law, there is a concrete adversarial relationship between the prosecution and the accused.
That should not be the case in a debate, at least not coming from the moderators/interviewers.
It is up to the other candidate to press when answers are too evasive.
And it is up to the viewing public to make up their mind whom they prefer to vote for.  Partially on the base of concrete answers, partially on their perception of the actual policies, partially on, yes, their emotional affinity for whom is vying for the job.  And that includes their perception of "straightness".

If the press has to hold politicians more accountable for concrete formulation of their policies, that's for press-to-candidate (singular, not plural) interviews.  Not a debate.
p.s. Both candidates were rather evasive as to their concrete policies.
*  And if anyone really thinks something as complex as "the economy" or "health care" can be covered in sufficient details to tell voters exactly what to expect during a 90min debate, they really are approaching this with a very different viewpoint than my jaded and cynical self.
Clarity in itself is not an endgame either.  On the economy:  "I am going to cut taxes" is clear enough in its intent to viewers, but rather nebulous in its effect on budget deficits, as Truss the Brief found out.

Not my DV, but fact-checking by the interviewer and them repeating a question are not exactly the same thing, although surely one can argue they are on a continuum of "pushiness" or even bias. OTOH, you're probably getting DVs because not everyone agrees with your view that politicians should say whatever they want and the host should just move on. See e.g. [pretty upvoted Q here] https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/32453/why-dont-politicians-get-fact-checked-immediately

They did repeat questions on a number of occasions.  Both speakers kinda dodged, at times.  Repeating questions does not magically grant the OP's wishes.

I very much disagree on the job of the moderator. It very much IS their job to correct falsehoods and misinformation. If they don't then debates derails, the conversation shifts towards non-issues, bullshit and personal attacks and the viewer comes off dumber than before. It also incentivizes bullshit as the fact checking capabilities of the opponent are limited compared to the bullshit someone could spout. Now the moderator should aim to rather to do it subtle like asking follow up questions hinting at a problematic double meaning rather than "you suck" but still that is their job.

@haxor789 I have already stated I don't mind the fact-checking, but that its reception highlights the risks when moderators are asked to do too much:  as in this question.  Ask yourself:  would you like to see Fox News anchors have an enhanced role if they were to moderate a future POTUS debate?
